# Session unexpectedly lose

Tags: php

I was wondering that why my session always losing unexpectedly. My website almost depends on session, if session lose, it will redirect to login page.

**Here is my code***

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])){
session_destroy();
header("Location:login.php");
exit();
}
include_once("action.php");
?>
```

How to fix it?? Thank in advance

Comment: You mean, session disappears after you close the browser?

Comment: Exactly what actions do you perform to reproduce this bug? Are you sure it's on this page?

Comment: Are you losing the session in between pages? Or is it never set in the first place? I notice you never actually declare the "login" session variable so no matter when this script runs it will start a session and destroy it because that variable is never set.

Comment: +1 to all three and please check my answer and tell me your opinion.

Comment: Show the code where you actually set `$_SESSION['login']`. also what's your session settings in `php.ini`?

Comment: @ring0, it is lose unexpectedly when i moved from page to page.

Comment: @Matchu, i want my site if user not yet login, it required login.

Comment: @DevonBernard, yeah, when i move from page to page. i have declared session "login" in login page, then i make to make sure that if user not yet login, it is required login.

Comment: @haim770, here is the code of session login:

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you lose your session when navigating between pages.

You need to include session_start(); on every single page that the user navigates to in order to continue their session.

Comment: not really. I think we should use `session_start();` in page that we want to work and use and change the sessions. and for example when a user navigates to a page that there is no session in it (and also `session_start();`) and back to a page with sessions in it (and also `session_start();`) sessions will still work.

Comment: @imsiso: Technically that is true but only for brief periods of time; sessions do expire so if a user spends a large amount of time on a page without a session_start(); then navigates back to a page without one the page session will not be recoverable. Also it never hurts to just put session_start(); on every page because this call always searches for a existing session first and continues it, and only creates a new session when an existing one is not found.

Comment: OMG. +1  to you and thank you. What a critical point I think it is.

Comment: but what about the thing I had experienced about `session_destroy();`? (using a `session_start();`before redirecting?

Comment: @imsiso: session_destroy(); should properly remove any set session variables (as long as session_start(); is called before the destroy statement). But it is too hard to tell without a code example; if you could show me the source code I would be glad to explain a solution to the bug you were having.

Comment: thanks in advance I will check it again in time and will post it as a question in stackoverflow.